# Использование вводных данных одного метода в другом

Tags: java, массивы

Есть класс для ввода и вводные х,у ,которые по идее координаты корабля.
Есть класс поле массив char 10 на 10, заполненный символом "." по дефолту. 
Мой идиотский вопрос- как использовать введенные х,у для отображения другого символа?
грубо говоря field[x][y]= 'O';
Комментарии в целом по вставленному куску тоже приветствуются

```
public class SeaBattle3 {
public static void battleField(){
    for (int k = 1;k<11;k++){
        System.out.print(k+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();

    char [][] field;
    field = new char[10][10];
    for( int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            field[j][i]= '.';
            System.out.print(field[j][i]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    char ship = new char[]
}

public static void logicOfPlaceOfShip()throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Введите координату Х: ");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String x = reader.readLine();
    char x2 = x.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Вы ввели "+x);
    System.out.println("Введите координату Y: ");
    String y = reader.readLine();
    char y2 = y.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Вы ввели "+y);
    System.out.println("Корабль поставлен в месте с координатами "+x+", "+y );
}

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    battleField();
    logicOfPlaceOfShip();
}
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите считать 2 числа - координаты точки (x;y) и затем в матрице `field` установить `fieldх[x][y] = 'O'`?

Comment: @Nikolay, ну да, как-то так. Я знаю, что это нубокод и я еще в процессе обучения. Просто этот вопрос не дает мне покоя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как писали ранее, `field` должно быть статической переменной класса (либо нестатической - но тогда и методы будут нестатические и нужно будет создать экземпляр класса).
Для считывания координат проще использовать `Scanner` и считывать сразу числа.

```
public class SeaBattle3 {
    private static char[][] field;
    private static void battleField() {
    for (int k = 1; k < 11; k++) {
        System.out.print(k + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
    field = new char[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            field[j][i] = '.';
            System.out.print(field[j][i] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    //char ship = new char[] - непонятная строка
}

private static void logicOfPlaceOfShip() {
    System.out.println("Введите координату Х: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Вы ввели " + x);
    System.out.println("Введите координату Y: ");
    int y = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Вы ввели " + y);
    scanner.close();
    field[x][y] = 'O';
    System.out.println("Корабль поставлен в месте с координатами " + x + ", " + y);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    battleField();
    logicOfPlaceOfShip();
}
```

}

Comment: спасибо! Пойду почитаю про Scanner

Answer (score 1):

> Есть класс поле массив char 10 на 10

«Поле» объявлено как локальная переменная `char [][] field;`. Локальная она потому что объявлена внутри метода `battleField`, а следовательно доступна только внутри метода и только пока работает метод.

Чтобы сохранять `field` и обращаться к нему из других методов попробуйте объявить его как статическое поле в классе:

```
private static final char[][] field = new char[10][10];

public static void battleField() {
...
//остальной код, объявление char[][] field внутри нужно будет убрать.
```

Затем к нему можно будет обращаться из любых методов класса

```
public static void logicOfPlaceOfShip()throws Exception{
    ...
    field[x][y] = 'O';
```

Нужно будет еще переделать логику, чтобы поле заполнялось только один раз, а выводилось неоднократно, но это Вы уже сами.

Comment: Премного благодарен за развернутый ответ! Понял в чем проблема

Comment: @Montego ну и постарайтесь не использовать `static` если уж учитесь

Comment: @rjhdby  в плане я слишком плохо в этом еще разбираюсь или в целом лучше не использовать?

Comment: @Montego думаю лучше будет разобраться что означает `static` и в каких случаях его нужно применять. Обычно поля, которые относятся к отдельному объекту не обозначают как `static`